# Limited By Value Postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a couple of rows where values in one column are repeating and I need to get a couple of rows where every value is limited by const.

For example, i have this rows (1, 'a') (2, 'b') (3, 'a') (4,'c') (5, 'b') (6, 'a') and i limited every value in select by 2. Then I should not get a row with ID 6 cause this is an extra row cause I limited them by 2.

How I can do that?
thx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just two columns, say `id` and `val`, and you want just one row per value, then aggregation is enough:

```
select min(id) as id, val
from mytable
group by val
```

If there are more columns, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (val) t.*
from mytable
order by val, id
```

Finally, if you want to be able to allow a variable number of rows per `val`, you can use window functions. Say you want 3 rows maximum per value:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by val order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 3
```

Comment: thank you very much! everything is working